# Advantage of using HAProxy AND Keepalived vs just Keepalived

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, high-availability, keep-alive

As per the (verbose) topic, are there any advantages over using a `Keepalived` & `HAProxy` as an HA webserver `loadbalancer` vs a pure keepalived solution?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Keepalived is working in layer 4 so doesn't have layer 7 knowledge at all. By using HAProxy and Keepalived together you can get benefit of having some options that HAProxy provides in layer 7 like [Stickiness](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/intro-1.6.html#3.3.6), [Sampling and converting information](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/intro-1.6.html#3.3.7), [ACLs and conditions](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/intro-1.6.html#3.3.9), [Content switching](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/intro-1.6.html#3.3.10), [Stick-tables](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/intro-1.6.html#3.3.11), [Formated strings](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/intro-1.6.html#3.3.12), [HTTP rewriting and redirection](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/intro-1.6.html#3.3.13), [Server protection](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/intro-1.6.html#3.3.14), [etc](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/intro-1.6.html).

If you only need to have a load balancer without any manipulating or any high level decision (layer 7) you can use only Keepalived and it will be faster because it works in layer 4.

Answer (score 0):

Administrators can use both Keepalived and HAProxy together for a more robust and scalable high availability environment. Using the speed and scalability of HAProxy to perform load balancing for HTTP and other TCP-based services in conjunction with Keepalived failover services, administrators can increase availability by distributing load across real servers as well as ensuring continuity in the event of router unavailability by performing failover to backup routers.

[keepalived and haproxy](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/load_balancer_administration/s2-lvs-keepalived-haproxy-vsa)